# How to use Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, relative-date, momentjs

I'm unable to follow the [Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/), and need some help with setting it up. I've referenced the `moment.min.js` file properly on my webpage like so:

```
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Coming to the HTML part of my webpage, I have two different datetime's on the same page:

**Published Date**

```
<time class="pubdate" datetime="2012-06-09T12:32:10-04:00" pubdate>
    June 09, 2012
</time>
```

**Last Modified Date**

```
<time class="updated" itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2012-06-09T12:32:10-04:00">
    June 9, 2012 ~ 12:32
</time>
```

**Important!** The relative date parsing shouldn't go beyond "yesterday". As for everything beyond, the `<time>` tags should display the exact datetime's they would without the JavaScript -- i.e. Moment.js shouldn't touch or parse dates that are past "yesterday".

Now, to make the library do its job as aforementioned, I need to call a function after the library reference. So, the question is, what should the function be? (Using jQuery is fine, as I already reference the library on my webpage.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please specify your question. I'm assuming you want a relative date parsing and the maximum should be "yesterday".

I never used moment.js but as far as the docs say, it's pretty simple.

Use `var now = moment();` as your current date. Then parse every `time`-Tag in your DOM with `var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));`

To check the difference use the `diff()` method:

```
if(now.diff(time, 'days') <= 1) {
    // getting the relative output
}
```

Use `var ago = now.from(time)` to get the relative output and replace the time in your DOM with your `ago` variable.

**Update based on comment**:

Okay, well untested, but that's the basic idea:

**Updated the code.**

```
var now = moment();

$('time').each(function(i, e) {
    var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));

    if(now.diff(time, 'days') <= 1) {
        $(e).html('<span>' + time.from(now) + '</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know JavaScript. And yes, I meant to say that the maximum should be "yesterday" and everything past that shouldn't be parsed.

Comment: Would be great if I can get little more help. **(1)** It's outputting **`in 19 hours`** — can it be something like **`19 hours ago`**?? **(2)** It replaces the whole thing, i.e. `<time class="pubdate" datetime="2012-06-09T12:32:10-04:00" pubdate>June 09, 2012</time>` is being replaced with for example, `<span>in 19 hours</span>`. Would it be possible to get to do something like this? `<time class="pubdate" datetime="2012-06-09T12:32:10-04:00" pubdate>19 hours ago</time>` — only replace the content inside <time> tag, i.e. replace `June 09, 2012` with `19 hours ago` and nothing else.

Comment: I updated the code, but please: When you want to build stuff with javascript, then learn javascript. Your questions are very, very basic. You really should spend some time learning the language.

Comment: Johannes, you are right. Actually I am planning to start learning JavaScript in a few days. Thanks again, for your time. :) The code works beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [`moment().calendar()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) function, which will format for you dates close to today (up to a week from today):

```
$('time').each(function(i, e) {
  var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));

  $(e).html('<span>' + time.calendar() + '</span>');
});​
```

You can customize the format strings with this code:

```
moment.calendar = {
  lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
  sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
  nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
  lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] LT',
  nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
  sameElse : 'L'
};
```

If you are not interested in formatting dates prior to yesterday, just change the formats of `lastWeek` and `nextWeek` to full date-time format (e.g. `'L'`).

---

**UPDATE 2013-09-06** Apparently it has a new syntax that also enables you to localize it:

```
moment.lang('en', {
  calendar: {
    lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
    sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
    nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
    lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] LT',
    nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
    sameElse : 'L'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JohannesKlauß for the code. This is basically how I executed his answer and how I am referencing the code on my website.

```
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/moment.executor.js"></script>
```

Where, **moment.min.js** is the Moment.js library, and **moment.executor.js** has this code (courtesy of Johannes):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var now = moment();

    $('time').each(function(i, e) {
        var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));

        if(now.diff(time, 'days') <= 1) {
            $(e).html('<span>' + time.from(now) + '</span>');
        }
    });

});
```

***PS:** You can actually edit **moment.min.js** and add the aforementioned code right in it, at the end. This way, you will be saving one additional HTTP request. :P*

Comment: The additional HTTP request is relatively insignificant but you could link to a [CDN](http://cdnjs.com/) that hosts the library if your number of requests are limited for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @its_me's implementation above, here's a version that

- updates all  elements with a given class
- keeps them updated every minute (so '1 minute ago' becomes '2 minutes ago')
- switches to a different format when +-1 day from now (e.g. Last Tuesday at 11:45 PM)

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/385gz/5/) for you to play with.

Your HTML:

```
<time class="cw-relative-date" datetime="2014-06-09T12:32:10-00:00"></time>
```

The JS to include:

```
(function () {

// Define a function that updates all relative dates defined by <time class='cw-relative-date'>
var updateAllRelativeDates = function() {
        $('time').each(function (i, e) {
            if ($(e).attr("class") == 'cw-relative-date') {

                // Initialise momentjs
                var now = moment();
                moment.lang('en', {
                    calendar : {
                        lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
                        sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
                        nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
                        lastWeek : '[Last] dddd [at] LT',
                        nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
                        sameElse : 'D MMM YYYY [at] LT'
                    }
                });

                // Grab the datetime for the element and compare to now                    
                var time = moment($(e).attr('datetime'));
                var diff = now.diff(time, 'days');

                // If less than one day ago/away use relative, else use calendar display
                if (diff <= 1 && diff >= -1) {
                    $(e).html('<span>' + time.from(now) + '</span>');
                } else {
                    $(e).html('<span>' + time.calendar() + '</span>');
                }
            }
        });
    };

// Update all dates initially
updateAllRelativeDates();

// Register the timer to call it again every minute
setInterval(updateAllRelativeDates, 60000);

})();
```