# moment is not defined - trying to reference moment function using ejs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, ejs

After loading the moment.min.js library, I test it with a script and it works fine.  Then, I try to reference the same moment function in the body of the html document using ejs, I get the error "moment is not defined"

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const x = moment().format()
        console.log(x)
    </script>
```

then, in the body ...

```
 <body>
  <h1><%= moment().format %></h1>
</body>
```

If I cant solve this, I will have figure a workaround.  Ideas?

Comment: You're confusing server-side code and client-side code. EJS runs on the server, <script> tags load the script on the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use node modules (like MomentJS) in EJS views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794860/how-to-use-node-modules-like-momentjs-in-ejs-views)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Yes, ejs runs on the server side.

Before this, I loaded the moment library in app.js with moment = require('moment').  And, I did not have the library loaded in the html file.  This is where my problem started.  I got the error "moment is not defined".  So, I tried loading the library in the html file.  So, I get the error when I reference any moment function with EJS.

Comment: Saurabh Mistry - perfect!  Therein lies the answer I needed.  Dont think I would have found the answer on my own.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To moment in your EJS files.

```
var moment = require('moment');
app.locals.moment = require('moment');
```

in view

```
<h1><%= moment().format() %></h1>
```