# Error with embedding moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, cdn

I am having difficulties including moment.js in my browser code. This is my first time using it and teaching myself to use a library, so any help is appreciated. I have a CDN for moment in my html page:

```
      <!-- jQuery cdn -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- moment.js cdn -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/af.js"></script>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var momentTest = moment(); 
      console.log(momentTest);  // this is not logging
    </script>
```

Also in my script.js file, I have tried calling it another way with format() like I saw in the docs:

```
 var now = moment().format();
 console.log(now); //this is not logging either
```

But I keep getting a console error - Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined. Can anyone help with this? I saw this article already but it didn't help me (total beginner with moment): [How to use Moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967736/how-to-use-moment-js)

Comment: It looks like you might be using a bad address for the moment cdn. I tried using `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>` and it worked fine. Can you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line does not load moment.js, but loads the `af` (Afrikaans) locale for moment.js.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/af.js"></script>
```

To load moment.js, you'd want to load the `moment.js` file instead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool thank you so much! I didn't even notice which was the correct one-just picked the top one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var momentTest = moment(); 
      console.log(momentTest);  // this is not logging
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't use the download link directly as a script. You should instead link to a CDN with moment.js such as [CloudFlare](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/), as these services are dedicated to serve scripts that way.