# html java script current time to cant add AM:PM

Tags: javascript, html, time

This is a Html and Javascript current time display code, I am trying to add `AM:PM` for this, but it does not display I am used for `var ampm = toda.getampm();` 
how to display correctly this format

example

**9 : 59 : 42 AM**

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + " : "  +  m + " : "  +  s ;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888491/how-do-you-display-javascript-datetime-in-12-hour-am-pm-format

Comment: @chiragsatapara I was read it, and im try this but not display

Comment: let me give you answer

Comment: you can use moment.js, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967736/how-to-use-moment-js

Comment: There's plenty of material about this stuff here on SO, just do some search - e.g
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: @core114, i update the answer , check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below answer

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  
  h = h % 12;
  h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  m = m < 10 ? '0'+ m : m;
  
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + " : "  +  m + " : "  +  s  + " " + ampm;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: i got it Thank you sir

Comment: You should have subtracted 12 from the var h after treating the am/pm thing. 13pm is quite redundant, isnt it?

Comment: @VictorLiaFook , now it's ok ?

Comment: @chiragsatapara cool. I think that it is ok now.

Comment: You will also need to limit `h` to values between 1 and 12 like this: `h=h%12; h=h?h:12;` after you have determined the AM / PM case.

Comment: @cars10m , check answer again , it's already there

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="time"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkTime(i) {

  if (i < 10) {

    i = "0" + i;

  }

  return i;

}


function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();

  var h = today.getHours();

  var m = today.getMinutes();

  var s = today.getSeconds();

  var am_pm= h >=12 ? "PM" : "AM";

  // add a zero in front of numbers<10

  m = checkTime(m);

  s = checkTime(s);

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + " : "  +  m + " : "  +  s + am_pm;

  t = setTimeout(function() {

    startTime()

  }, 500);

}

startTime();

</script>

</html>
```